# How to commit or push in git using command in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, git

I want to commit newly created file in git using php

```
Storage::put( $input['people'].'.txt',  $input['people']);
        $output = exec('git -c add .', $shell_output,$status);
$output1 = shell_exec('git -c user.name="gitusername" -c user.email="gitemail" commit -m "Created new file named: '. $input['people'] .'"');
        $output2 = shell_exec('git push origin master 2>&1');
```

This is not commiting or pushing code to git.

Comment: It's because of you are exiting the script with `dd($status);` The other lines doesn't run.

Comment: @CanVural even though i remove it is not committing and pushing data

Comment: @CanVural does it require username/password setup of git?

Comment: Can you dump the $outputs?

Comment: check this repo https://gist.github.com/rufhausen/5e4c746e0150b6aa1d44